# list comprehension with multiple if statements

Tags: python, numpy, max, list-comprehension

I have 4 lists and i want to have a final list with the maximum of each index of all lists and also to which list it belongs
If it is from first list i mark 'a' ,and so on...
But i have a problem with list comprehension.There is a syntax which i cannot find:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[1,200],[4,5]])
b=np.array([[11,33],[65,666]])
c=np.array([[1,2040],[54,522]])
d=np.array([[1,3],[685,222]])


x,y=a.shape

m=[]

for i in np.arange(x):
  for j in np.arange(x):
    maximum=max ( a[i][j] ,b[i][j],c[i][j] ,d[i][j])
    m.append ((maximum,['a' if maximum in a  else 'b'  if maximum in b  else 'c'  if maximum in c else 'd'  if maximum in d ]  ))
```

where is my error in list comprehension??

Comment: What output do yo uget that you're not expecting? what should it be?

Comment: You can't concat multiple if else like that. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html

Comment: dont use list comprehension if you need to make a massive line like that

Comment: You're not using a list comprehension but a conditional expression which can be corrected to the following: `m.append ((maximum,'a' if maximum in a  else 'b'  if maximum in b  else 'c'  if maximum in c else 'd'  if maximum in d else None))`  After this correction, your code works.

Comment: Although it doesn't matter with the given arrays, in general it should of course be `for j in np.arange(y):` (with `y` rather than `x`).

Comment: DarrylJG thank you!! that was i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general rule for creating a list of comprehension

```
[expression for item in iterable if condition == True]
```

In your case, you are totally missing iterable. Also, your conditions are not correct.

I assume you want to get a list of max values for each column and the name of the list where this value is.
In this case you could use that list of comprehension:

```
m.append((maximum,[name for lis, name in ((a, 'a'), (b, 'b'), (c, 'c'), (d, 'd')) if maximum in lis]))
```

Answer (score 1):

NumPy arrays are much more than just nested lists. For example, you can easily collect your four arrays into one 3d-array:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,200], [4,5]])
b = np.array([[11,33], [65,666]])
c = np.array([[1,2040], [54,522]])
d = np.array([[1,3], [685,222]])

abcd = np.stack([a, b, c, d])
abcd.shape
```

```
(4, 2, 2)
```

Now the maximum for each index pair over the original arrays can be obtained very conveniently:

```py
np.max(abcd, axis=0)
```

```
array([[  11, 2040],
       [ 685,  666]])
```

To get the index number for which list each maximum number came from, you can use [`np.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```py
np.argmax(abcd, axis=0)
```

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 1]], dtype=int64)
```

Here, `1` means `b`, `2` means `c`, etc. because we stacked `a, b, c, d` in that order.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just stack he arrays first, and use numpy methods:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,200],[4,5]])
b = np.array([[11,33],[65,666]])
c = np.array([[1,2040],[54,522]])
d = np.array([[1,3],[685,222]])

s = np.stack((a,b,c,d))
```

Now you can easily find the index of the maximum (so 0 => a, 1 => b, etc):

```
max_value = s.max(axis=0)
argmax_value = s.argmax(axis=0)
```

And you can even stack them together:

```
result = np.dstack((max_value, argmax_value)).reshape(-1, 2)

# array([[  11,    1],
#        [2040,    2],
#        [ 685,    3],
#        [ 666,    1]], dtype=int64)
```

If you really need the letters in your list, you can now map the second column to your letters:

```
# should not be too many arrays... ;-)
mapper = {i: chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(s.shape[0])}
result_list = [(x, mapper[y]) for x, y in result]
```

But generally, if your logic needs to know the name of a variable, the design is wrong. You should probably use a sequence container then (list, array, etc), like the stacked array in the first code box.